# Is x in Q(x) free variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(\forall x)(P(x)\lor (\exists  y)R(y))\rightarrow Q(x)$
I think the variable 'x' in Q(x) is not bounded.Because  $(\forall x)$ only works left.But I am not sure about it.

From the definition in Wikipedia :[free variable and bounded variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). A bound variable is a variable that was previously free, but has been bound to a specific value or set of values called domain of discourse or universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct ... the $x$ in $Q(x)$ is not within the scope of any quantifier quantifying $x$ and so it is free.